# Java EE Security Authenticating through VO

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish

In my work I have to use a login resource which consists in a large set of jar files. The login resource is like (excerpt of the login servlet):

```
IntranetAutenticacao intranetAutenticacao = new IntranetAutenticacao();
  if(!intranetAutenticacao.isAutenticado(request, response)){
      response.sendRedirect(intranetAutenticacao.urlPaginaLogin);
      return;
  }

  UsuarioVO usuarioVO = intranetAutenticacao.usuarioVO;

 if(intranetAutenticacao.isAutenticado(request, response,requisicao,requisicao)){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("usuarioVO", usuarioVO);
            response.sendRedirect(requisicao+"?dependencia="+usuarioVO.getCodDependencia()+"&chave="+usuarioVO.getChave()+"&nome="+usuarioVO.getNome()+"&funcao="+usuarioVO.getCodCargo());
        }             
}
```

After a desired page request, the resource prompts the Company's login page for user authentication and, as it is succesfully authenticated, the resource returns a bean (VO) filled with user info (session attributes, like employee name, id etc).

Since the Company denied my request for a LDAP user bind - to use JEE7 Security, see below - I'm wondering about how can I use that Company authenticated VO (mentioned above) along with the JEE7 Security (so I could use access control through roles, groups etc). Is it possible? How can I do it?

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check" name="loginForm">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what app server are you using?

Comment: Sorry not mentioned that: Glassfish 4 OpenSource Edition.